# AppCompatActivity Gives Error

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I use version of Android Studio 1.5.1

If I create new project and MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity then it does not work it gives error like:

```
    12-02 11:55:20.736 29178-29214/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
12-02 11:55:45.099 29225-29225/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.poonam.demoappcompatactivity/com.example.poonam.demoappcompatactivity.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built with an incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat.
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2077)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built with an incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat.
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:726)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:53)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:525)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:74)
                                                       at com.example.poonam.demoappcompatactivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:10)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576) 
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
12-02 11:55:48.855 233-4816/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
```

I create new project. Not change anything only run it.but it gives error.
How can i use AppCompatActivity.

Comment: did you solved your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Your logcat throws

> This app has been built with an incorrect configuration.

You should use latest **gradle plagin version**

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2' //2.2.0
```

**Here is Demo**

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

**FYI**

You can add this in your **`build.gradle`** section .

```
    android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
}
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild, Sync & Run**.